# Notification Aurelia-KendoUI-bridge with Typescript

Tags: kendo-ui, typescript, notifications, aurelia

View:

```
<ak-notification id="popupNotification"
               k-widget.bind="popupNotification"></ak-notification>
```

ViewModel:

```
this.popupNotification.show('error message', 'error');
```

However, the this.popupNotification has no reference in the .ts file. How can I add use it in ViewModel to show the popup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declared the variable with the same name as id. and it worked fine.

```
popoupNotification;
```